# SQL Server run trigger background

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, t-sql

In PHP, SQL Server,

PHP going to insert the lacks of records, for each I am calling a trigger.

Trigger will took nearly 20 min to complete the trigger process, so my PHP script waiting 20 min for every insert, so how run the trigger process in the background and continue the PHP insert process instead of waiting for 20 min for each insert.

Any advise in PHP or SQL Server.

Comment: I would consider a radical redesign. A tigger consuming 20 min, makes a database unusuable.

Comment: Agree with @bummi.  How about making the trigger insert a record in another table and then using that table as a work queue that is processed by a background task.  This would need some kind of background process, so not sure you can do this in pure PHP, but I'm not a PHP expert.

Comment: we dont completly thing in PHP, but just like using some server variables to make the trigger in background process. like in linux to execute command in background we have add & at the end of the command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve this problem, you need to fix the reason why your trigger is taking 20 minutes to execute - it's possibly doing a table scan instead of an index scan to check something exists I'm guessing, or using cursors.

To answer your question however, make a second table (without a trigger), insert the row in there, then have a SQL job that runs every x minutes and takes the data out of that table, and inserts into your main table that has the slow trigger.

Answer (score 0):

i think that you can execute a task .
The task are asyncronous (i think)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/execute-sql-task?view=sql-server-ver15